# Angular Google Maps - Unable to Patch Value using PlaceResult Object on Autocomplete Directive

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete to add an address autocomplete control on my form. The control successfully provides addresses when the user begins typing and I am able to retrieve the user's selection as well. My issue arises when I try to take the user selected address and patch it to the form. I have created an example to demo my issue below.

I have created an issue directly in GitHub but there has not been any movement. Therefore, I am deciding to reach out here. If interested see https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete/issues/322

Can someone explicitly show me an example of how to update the autocomplete control's value?

Thank you for your help.

**Versions**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.2.13
Node: 14.17.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1102.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1102.13
@angular-devkit/core               11.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.2.13
@angular/cdk                       11.2.12
@angular/cli                       11.2.13
@angular/flex-layout               12.0.0-beta.34
@angular/material                  11.2.12
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.12
@schematics/angular                11.2.13
@schematics/update                 0.1102.13
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.0.7
```

```
"@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete": "^6.2.1"
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" #ngForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addressSubmit($event)">
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Tell us where they are located</mat-label>
        <input matInput matGoogleMapsAutocomplete [types]="['address']" country="us" (onAutocompleteSelected)="onAutocompleteSelected($event)" formControlName="address" placeholder="Search Address">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="button-container">
        <ion-button type="submit">Save and Continue</ion-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
export class myPage implements OnInit {

    public addressForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
    
        this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            address: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        });
           
        this.getData();
    }

    public getData() {
             
         const myAddress: PlaceResult = { place_id : 'ChIJcw5BAI63t4kRj5qZY1MSyAo', name: '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW', formatted_address: '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA' };

         this.addressForm.patchValue({
             address: myAddress
         });
    }

    onAutocompleteSelected(result: PlaceResult) {
        console.log('result: ', result);
    }

    public addressSubmit(event) {
        console.log('addressSubmit(event)');
    }
}
```